# Problem in Spatialite database creation

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, database, spatialite

When I try create a new database, Spatialite plugin return the dialog error box:

```
The SQL query seems to be invalid, no such table: views_goemetry_columns
```

When I click in OK button, a second dialog box (Transform database into SpatiaLite) is open with the text :

```
This database seems to be a valid SQLite database but not a valid SpatiaLite One
Would you like QSpatiaLite to automatically transform it to SpatiaLite (information won't be lost) ?
```

When I click in the YES button, a new dialog error box open with the text:

```
Unable to convert Database to SpatiaLite
```

When I click in OK button, another dialog error box open with the text:

```
The SQL query seems to be invalid.
```

The database was set up, but I can't import spatial layers.
How resolve this problem?

Comment: "whe I try to create a new database" Using what?

Comment: I got the same problem, so thank you for your answer, but how do you then import spatialitegui into QGIS ?

Comment: You don't import spatialite_gui. You just use the file that this tool creates. Thats the point of spatialite / sqlite.

Comment: To say it the other way round: You create the database table with the gui, but you can fill/modify/show the data with Qgis.

Answer (score 3):

as Ragi Yaser Burhum alread stated: >>"when I try to create a new database" Using what?<<

the easiest and safest way to create a spatialite-database : use the free spatialitegui ( gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index) from the spatialite developer and then import into qgis...
seems like your database is missing the geometry columns and is therefore a simple nonspatial sqlite databse

Comment: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index  simply copying & pasting the URL above doesn't work since it's using https

Comment: Rayner and Kurt,